# Drupal : How to export node content to other website?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to fetch contents from my Drupal site and show it on another site using CURL. I already have a module that creates a URL (menu) in Drupal and outputs the requested node using node_load() method. This way, I can select which specific fields to output to the requesting site.

However, I also have a module that alters the node's content. What is does is when a node is viewed, it looks for the img tags in the content and replaces the source attribute with its thumbnail version. In this module I look for a specific attribute of the node :

```
$node->content['body']['#value']
```

And replace the img tags if present..

My problem is when i call node_load() in the menu I defined on the first paragraph, it doesnt have that $node->content['body']['#value'] that's why the image tags are not replaced..

Thanks!

Comment: Not directly related but you may want to save yourslef some work and use http://drupal.org/project/imagecache instead of thumbnailing images yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`node_view`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_view/6) to theme the display of the node and invoke modules changing the node output.

Comment: what do you mean when you say 'invoke modules changing node output'? will it possible to get the final output of node's content as i may have a better chance dealing with the final output..

Comment: @r2b2 `hook_nodeapi`, that is what your module should be using to alter `$node->content['body']['#value']`. When a node is prepared for display, `hook_nodeapi` is invoked allowing modules to alter the node content. So using `node_view` will fix your problem (if you implemented `hook_nodeapi` to make your custom changes)